# Interpretation of the Linear regression model using ggplot2

Tags: r, regression, model, ggplot2, marketing

I used `ggplot()` for visualization and linear regression in R for this model.

I am not confident if I interpreted the model right. These are my thoughts. The $p$-value is large and R-squared is fairly small which means there is no strong correlation between my variables Spend and Impressions.

For 0 dollars spent we will get 35,081 impressions (i.e., the intercept). For 1,000 dollars spent we will get 48,681 impressions (i.e., $48,681 = 35,081 + 13.6 \times 1,000$).

Can someone help me with the interpretation of the graph? I would say there is a weak, positive correlation. The data is scattered outside of the 95% confidence band. Also, any thoughts or recommendations on improving the model and it's interpretation?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

That `ggplot` has little to do with the regression model you fit. To get the plot to correspond to your regression model, you need to enter `method = "lm"` in the call to `geom_smooth()`. That will produce a straight line that corresponds to the regression you fit. It's also a good idea to have the plot that you made, i.e., with the smoothed fit line, but just know it doesn't relay the same information as your regression.

The confidence bands around the line are unrelated to the points. They are confidence bounds for the line itself, not for points along the line, so it doesn't tell you anything that points are outside the confidence band. If a flat straight line can fit completely within the confidence band, then your slope is not significant. The confidence bands (resulting from `geom_smooth()` with `method = "lm"`) come directly from the slope and intercept standard errors from the regression model. You can see that even in the smoothed fit line that you produced here, the confidence bands are consistent with a flat, straight line at $Y \approx 39500$, indicating that there being no relationship between the predictor and outcome is consistent with your data. (Note this doesn't mean there is no relationship; it just means if there is a relationship, it didn't show up in your sample.)

Answer (score 0):

Please accept @Noah's answer.

In addition, I want to offer a few suggestions with respect to best practices when you're pre-processing your data. I don't think they are trivial; they will save you from making unnecessary mistakes in the future. First, your function call is a bit messy. It is recommended to use snake case when naming variables and to avoid unnecessary white space. Second, use the `data = ...` argument inside of the `lm()` function; it will save you keystrokes. Moreover, try to avoid naming your dataset something like "data" or any other popular function or function argument. Some may balk at this and say it is unnecessary, but I would disagree. Use helpful naming conventions. This is useful when you walk away from a project for a long period of time.

For example:

```
linear_model <- lm(paid_search_impr ~ spend, data = ...)
```

If you have many columns with awkward spacing and/or capitals, try this quick-and-dirty fix from the [snakecase](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snakecase/snakecase.pdf) package:

```
df <- tidyr::tibble(
  `paid search impr` = c(1000, 10000, 100000),
  `Spend`            = c(100, 200, 300)
  )

snakecase::to_snake_case( colnames(df) )  # feed it the column names; you could also use names(df)
[1] "paid_search_impr" "spend"
```

And finally, I have no qualms with your interpretation, other than you predicting a large increase in "impressions" when assessing 1,000 dollar increments in spending. Is this reasonable? I only ask because you will be well outside the bounds of your data. Something to think about. As for your trend line, the call to `geom_smooth()` defaults to a smoothing routine. It's visually appealing and is more likely to overfit in areas where there is *more data*. Note the tightness of the band in the region where $x = 350$.

A linear (i.e., `method = "lm")` trend line would be a far less dramatic representation of the overall trend, as the linear fit uses the *full range* of $x$ values to estimate the regression line.

Anyway, these are just some helpful tips!